# How do i use head method in routes in laravel ? something like this Route::head('abc/{id}', 'def@ghi');

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to check if the resource exists or not for that I am supposed to use head method. I gave route something like this

```
Route::head('abc/{id}', 'def@ghi');
```

but it gives me 500 internal server errors without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`head` isn't a method available on the Router, `Illuminate\Routing\Router`.

All the `get` routes you make are also setup for `head`.

```
/**
 * Register a new GET route with the router.
 *
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @param  \Closure|array|string|callable|null  $action
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 */
public function get($uri, $action = null)
{
    return $this->addRoute(['GET', 'HEAD'], $uri, $action);
}
```